# Is there a way to "unwrap" IO monad in Haskell inside another io action?

Tags: haskell

In particular I want to use pure Haskell functions on the results on console input. I'm curious if exists something like `?` operator from rust.
this snippet complains that words expect the type String, while its supplied wrapped into an io action. But i can't even use `>>=` operator since as far as i understand i cannot instantiate IO constructor directly. So, does it mean all the standard library functions can't work with io even in the scope of io action?

```hs
thing :: IO ()
thing = do
    let mbwords = words $ getLine ;
```

Comment: it's unclear what you're trying to do - could you expand on your example a little? Note that you can do `fmap words getLine` to get an IO action that reads a line from the console and splits it into words, and of course you can in side a `do` block do `someString <- getLine` and then call whatever pure functions you want with `someString` in the subsequent code.

Comment: I'm not sure what the connection is between "instantiating IO constructors directly" and using the `>>=` operator. But are you aware that `pure` / `return` allow you to make an "IO value" out of any value you like? They have type `a -> IO a` (or more generally `a -> m a` for any `Monad m`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since Haskell is not designed to be totally useless, there must be a way. And there is more than one indeed.

What you looking for is something like this

```
main = do
  line <- getLine
  let mbwords = words line
```

or perhaps

```
main = do
  mbwords <- fmap words getLine
```

Note you use `<-` to "open" the monadic value inside the do-block, not `let`.

Also note instantiating IO constructors is not necessary as long as you have functions that return IO actions, such as `print`. You can express the same idea with

```
main = fmap words getLine >>= print
```

(of course you can use an arbitrary action of the right type instead of `print`).

Comment: Am i right to understand that this means let clause is not identical to <- in the context of IO actions

Comment: @HerbalTea If it were, we wouldn't have both.

Comment: @HerbalTea The `let` statement in a do block is not identical to the `<-` statement, in any context whatsoever. They only both exist in the language because they do **different** things.

Comment: They are not identical, and also I don't buy this argument that if they were we wouldn't have them both. There's plenty of redundancy, and indeed even the original Haskell Report is written in part by giving translations from programs in Haskell to programs in a smaller subset of Haskell.

Comment: `do let x = y; ...` is equivalent to `let x = y in do ...`. Like all the syntax in a `do` block, it's meant to suggest the kind of imperative programming that you do when you have side effects like assignment available. `line <- getLine; ...` is not an assignment; it's syntactic sugar for `getLine >>= \line -> ...`. The action `getLine` is "bound" to a function `\line -> ...` in a way defined by `>>=` in the `Monad` instance for the `IO` type constructor.

Comment: @DanielWagner I wasn't thinking of a general argument that any two syntactic features wouldn't exist if they did the same thing, but a more specific one about `let` vs `<-` bindings in `do` blocks. `let` statements are a trivial variation on `let ... in` expressions, which do a fundamental and obvious job; they were "always going to exist", in some form, even if nobody had thought of monads. But `<-` bindings were *added* to the language to allow imperative-structured code; if that could already be achieved by simply replacing the `<-` with `let` nobody would have bothered to define them.

Comment: @Ben I guess what I'm really trying to do is voice support for the existence of the question. I think it's easy to read the answer "if those were they same we wouldn't have them both" and hear an implied "and therefore you should have been able to figure out the answer yourself without asking". I don't claim that either person answering had that implied continuation in their head, only that a beginner that's floundering could easily have it in *their* head. BTW, I really appreciate your expanded version, because it's much clearer that the intended reading is as a history lesson.